# Date conversion and date formatting

Tags: r

How to convert 6/5/2017 12:00:00 AM -04:00 date and time to lubridate mdy_hms with 24 hours in R?  I've tried

```
as.POSIXct("6/5/2017 12:00:00 AM -04:00",format = "%m/%d/%Y %hh:%M:%S", tz = "UTC")
```

but it return in 12 hours format and not 24 hours, I have data frame worth of 2 years data therefore I need to be able to return 2pm as 14 and 2am as 2.

Answer (score 0):

I think your formatting string is wrong.

?strptime describes the formatting string. The string below is untested - if it doesn't work, check ?strptime and update it.

Your formatting string currently is correct for the day string, but for the time string it implies a 24hr number and ignores the AM/PM.

Edited: actual string should be:

```
as.POSIXct("6/5/2017 12:00:00 AM -0400",format = "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p %z", tz = "UTC")
```

NB the timezone must NOT have a colon in it so that may need string manipulation to remove first.

Comment: i tired it but It didn't work

Comment: Did you remove the colon from the timezone (even just in a test piece of data)? Also by 'didn't work' - what happened?

Comment: I've updated the answer with a working demo.

Comment: thanks but i want it to ignore the -04:00 and just return "2017-06-05 24:00:00"

Comment: Then just edit the string to remove the timezone before passing it through POSIXct, and drop the %z from the formatting string.